# Multiple individual graphs from a unique dataframe

Tags: r, graph, dplyr

I know that some subjects are about similar questions, but even using those I was not able to resolve the issue on my own. Thus, I am sorry if this subject appears as a duplicate but I am a bit stuck.

I have to draw nearly 40 graphs representing body temperature variations accross 24hours (a graph per individual of the study). To do that, I tried to write a loop using `dplyr`and `ggplot2` packages. You may find bellow an exemple of my data. There are numerous missing values but I don't think it represents an issue regarding the current question.

```
structure(list(heures = structure(1:13, .Label = c("01:00:00", 
"03:00:00", "05:00:00", "07:00:00", "08:00:00", "10:00:00", "12:00:00", 
"13:30:00", "15:00:00", "17:00:00", "19:00:00", "21:00:00", "23:00:00"
), class = "factor"), x1= c(36.55, 36.5, 36.44444444, 
36.6, 36.86666667, 37.26, 37, NA, NA, 37.3, 37.1, 37, 35.6), 
    x2 = c(NA, 34.5, 35.4, 36.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), x3 = c(36.9, 36.4, NA, NA, 36.9, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 37.5, 37.5, 36.9, 37.1), x4 = c(36, 
    35.8, NA, NA, NA, 37.4, 36.7, 36.3, NA, 37.5, 37, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

So far, I have written the following code with "indiv" being a dataframe containing the above presented data.

```
names <- c(colnames(indiv))

graph <- list()

test <- function(df, names) {

  for (i in 1:length(df)) {

    name <- names[i]

    stock <- df %>%
      filter(heures, !!name)

    graph[[i]] <- ggplot(data=stock, aes(x=heures, y=stock[,2])) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(x="Hours (HH:MM:SS)",
           y="Temperature",
           title=colnames(stock[2]))

  }

  return(graph)

}
```

It returns an error that seems to indicate the filter function does not work properly:

```
Warning messages:
 1: In Ops.factor(~heures, ~"x1") :
  ‘&’ not meaningful for factors
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in this. I also tried a code without the dplyr part present in the current loop, but it didn't gave me the wanted output neither.

Thank you in advance for your advises.

Comment: please add enough sample data so we can run your code... for eample: what does `indiv` look like?

Comment: +1 @Wimpel.  Also, if your input dataset is structured correctly, there should be no need to use a loop to do this.

Comment: All my apologies for being not clear enough about this. The sample data corresponds to the "indiv" dataframe cited in the code. I'll edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: @Limey : If a solution without loop exists I would be glad to hear about it. I just didn't find any so far...

Comment: I am working on it using `lapply` but I am facing some difficulties to keep names of the individual inside the function creating plots

Comment: done, posted an idea as an answer. If I understand correctly, you are not interested in the `facet` option but instead you want independent plots (one for each individual)

Comment: Indeed, that's why I was trying a loop instead of using the `facet` or the `multiplot` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have came out with this idea : tidy a little the dataset to make it easier to use with ggplot and then split it and store the splitted dataframe in a list. Then I use `lapply` to avoid using a loop along with a custom function to create plots.

This is not a very fast way if you have a lot of data but I use this trick a lot with small datasets.
This code creates a plot for each individual (not facets).

```
library(tidyverse) # all functions of these packages are not necessary here

df = structure(list(heures = structure(1:13, .Label = c("01:00:00", 
                                                   "03:00:00", "05:00:00", "07:00:00", "08:00:00", "10:00:00", "12:00:00", 
                                                   "13:30:00", "15:00:00", "17:00:00", "19:00:00", "21:00:00", "23:00:00"
), class = "factor"), x1= c(36.55, 36.5, 36.44444444, 
                            36.6, 36.86666667, 37.26, 37, NA, NA, 37.3, 37.1, 37, 35.6), 
x2 = c(NA, 34.5, 35.4, 36.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
       NA, NA, NA, NA), x3 = c(36.9, 36.4, NA, NA, 36.9, 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, 37.5, 37.5, 36.9, 37.1), x4 = c(36, 
                                                                               35.8, NA, NA, NA, 37.4, 36.7, 36.3, NA, 37.5, 37, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                               -13L))


# tidy your data, good practice makes it easier to plot things with ggplot
df = df %>% pivot_longer(2:ncol(df), names_to = "individual", values_to = "temperature")

# I would do it this way:
df_list = split(df, df$individual)

plot_fun = function(df) {
  title = unique(df$individual)
  ggplot(df, aes(x=heures, y=temperature))+
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = title)
  #### add here things to save your plots, store them somewhere, etc
}
lapply(df_list, FUN = plot_fun)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll try what your suggesting there.

Comment: Feel free to have a look [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) and [there](https://juba.github.io/tidyverse/index.html) (as you seem to speak French) ;) I use these a lot to "tidy" my data before making plots.

Comment: I do speak French ;) Thank you again for your help, I'll have a look to the link you gave. I still have a lot to learn regarding r!

Answer (score 0):

Using toy data as your data frame is incomplete:

```
df <- tibble(
        X=rep(1:10, times=2),
        Y=c(1:10, seq(10, 1, -1)),
        Name=rep(c("Patient 1", "Patient 2"), each=10)
      )

df %>% ggplot() +
         geom_line(aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
         facet_grid(rows=vars(Name))
```

Giving
[image]

Comment: If I understand well, individuals are not in columns anymore instead you suggest to create a third column to store the names. Is that right?

Comment: That's my assumption.  Your sample dataset doesn't indicate how `name`s are defined.  If `name`s are in a different dataset, then there must be some way to join them to the dataset containing the information you need to plot.

Comment: `Names` are strings of caracters and it is possible to join them in this kind of way. However, as there is around 40 graphs to plot, I'm affraid it'll be difficult to read using this approach.

Comment: Then perhaps [`facet_grid_paginate`](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggforce/man/facet_grid_paginate.html) might help.

Comment: I'll have a look. In any case, even if I don't use it right now it'll be additionnal tools to use in future projects! Thank you for your help